# Iptable rule to log all outbound connections outside subnet

Tags: networking, network-programming, iptables

I want to log all new outbound tcp connections excluding connections happening to localhost and IPs in same network.

This is how I am setting it up, but I see outbound connections to 127.0.0.1 and to 192.168.1.122 which is my IP. I also see outbound connections to 192.168.1.121 which is in same subnet.

```
    sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -p tcp --state NEW ! -s 127.0.0.1 ! -d 127.0.0.1 -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  "

    for i in $(hostname -I)
    do
    echo $i
    sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -p tcp --state NEW -s 127.0.0.1 ! -d $i/24 -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  "
    done
```

Here is output of iptables-save after this script, I have snipped the output to just capture this rule.

```
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 0:65535 -j f2b-outbound

    -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 172.17.0.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 10.97.11.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A OUTPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 172.17.0.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 10.97.11.0/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A OUTPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1/32 ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  " --log-uid
    -A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables-save` after you run your script?

Comment: Edited to show the iptables-save.

Answer (score 4):

The connections are being logged by your very first `iptables` line. It will match all non-localhost packets, as the matching criteria is source not-localhost AND destination not-localhost. Also your additional rules will never match as an outbound packet will never have a source address of 127.0.0.1/8 (localhost subnet).

You need to change the line in your `for` loop from

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -p tcp --state NEW -s 127.0.0.1 ! -d $i/24 -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  "
```

to

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -p tcp --state NEW ! -d $i/24 -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  "
```

Comment: So I should remove first rule altogether and change second one as shown by you, I will try that but I found "outbound packet will never have a source address of 127.0.0.1/8 (localhost subnet)." this confusing. I mentioned -s 127.0.0.1, wont all outbound packets have that as source address ?

Comment: Outbound packets will (as a rule) have a source address assigned to the outbound interface. If your `eth0` interface has `192.168.0.10` assigned to it then the majority (or all) packets exiting that interface will have the source address of `192.168.0.1`. The localhost subnet (127.0.0.1) does not leave the host at all, and you should never see a `127` address on the wire.